# Attempting to store unique strings from text file in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue with one of my loops entering a string into excel. I am extracting data from a text file that can be any length, but everything I've used so far is anywhere between 100 lines of data and 50000 lines of data. The string I am attempting to extract is 4 characters long, most often numbers, but can be alphanumeric. By default the characters are 0001, 0002, 0003, and 0004 but this is completely up to our customers if they choose to use any other 4 characters. When entering the data in Excel, I am wanting only the unique values entered.

The whole code can be given, but everything else works fine so I don't think it's necessary. If you think so, request and I'll edit it in. Keep in mind that I've tried many different attempts at this and the logic never seems to work out.

The result is a long list of rows with every value from the text file.

If I had to guess, this is due to the string being a number and then excel storing it as just "2" instead of "0002" so I have formatted the entire column to show 4 characters. Even then I think Excel sees it as just "2" so the string never matches the data.

Any help is appreciated.

```
FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Open FileName For Input As #1

strSearch = "MTRDT"

Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, ReadData
    If Left(ReadData, Len(strSearch)) = strSearch Then
            MtrdtCount = MtrdtCount + 1
            MeterType = Mid(ReadData, 78, 4)
            lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            MeterTypeTest = True

            For Each cell In Range("G3:G" & lastrow)
                If MeterType = cell.Value Then
                    MeterTypeTest = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next cell

            If MeterTypeTest = True Then
                Range("G" & MeterTypeCnt) = MeterType
                MeterTypeCnt = MeterTypeCnt + 1

            End If
    Else
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your data has been entered using the method shown, Excel won't be seeing the data entered as `0002` as the number `2` - it will be seeing it as the string `"0002"`.

But you are testing those values against `"'" & Mid(ReadData, 78, 4)`, which means you will be comparing `"0002"` against `"'0002"`.

You need to add that `'` character as you enter the data to the cell, not before doing the comparison.  So the following should work:

```
FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Open FileName For Input As #1

strSearch = "MTRDT"

Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, ReadData
    If Left(ReadData, Len(strSearch)) = strSearch Then
        MtrdtCount = MtrdtCount + 1
        MeterType = Mid(ReadData, 78, 4)
        lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        MeterTypeTest = True

        For Each cell In Range("G3:G" & lastrow)
            If MeterType = cell.Value Then
                MeterTypeTest = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell

        If MeterTypeTest Then
            Range("G" & MeterTypeCnt) = "'" & MeterType
            MeterTypeCnt = MeterTypeCnt + 1
        End If
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: That was a mistake when posting. I was in the middle of an edit when I broke down and asked. Thanks for the help, adding the "'" to both and changing it to If MeterTypeTest Then worked. I tried storing MeterType as just the string without the ' and tested without the ' but got the same issue as before. Any idea what was happening there?

Comment: @Cody If you didn't have the `'` when you entered a string of `"0002"` into the cell, Excel would store it as the number `2` and that would then not match when later compared against `"0002"`.  (It would actually be comparing `"0002"` from the file against `"2"`, because VBA would cast the number `2` to the string `"2"` to do the comparison.)  So you need the `'` when storing the data, but need to remember that the `'` isn't really part of the cell's contents so you have to check the other data in the file against `"0002"`, not `"'0002"`.  Confusing?  Yes.

Comment: That's what I was thinking was happening. The bad thing is the next loop I have to work on is text and I probably would have been able to confirm the issue there. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think set column "G"'s numberformatLocal  as bellow

```
Columns("g").NumberFormatLocal = "@"


Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Open Filename For Input As #1

strSearch = "MTRDT"

Do Until EOF(1)
Line Input #1, ReadData
    If Left(ReadData, Len(strSearch)) = strSearch Then
            MtrdtCount = MtrdtCount + 1
            MeterType = Mid(ReadData, 78, 4)
            lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            MeterTypeTest = True

            For Each cell In Range("G3:G" & lastrow)
                If MeterType = cell.Value Then
                    MeterTypeTest = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next cell

            If MeterTypeTest = True Then
                Range("G" & MeterTypeCnt) = MeterType
                MeterTypeCnt = MeterTypeCnt + 1

            End If
    Else
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: That did it. I had to add the statement to remove the number stored as text error after running this the first time.